# Marcar checkbox 'irmão' com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho dois `checkbox` diferentes numa mesma coluna da tabela, mas ambos possuem nomes e values diferentes.

```
<td align="center">
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkSiapeServidor" name="chkSiapeServidor"/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkIdUnidadeAnterior" name="chkIdUnidadeAnterior"/>
</td>
```

Ao carregar a página, verifico se um `hidden` está preenchido e caso positivo seto o valor do `hidden` no checkbox. Utilizo este código:

```
if($('#siapeServidor').prop('value')) {
    $(this).find('td input[type=checkbox][name=chkSiapeServidor][value='+$('#siapeServidor').prop('value')+']').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Como faço para marcar o `checkbox` que está no mesmo nível que o referenciado, e como referenciar o `tr` pai do `td` onde estão localizados?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- para referienciar o próximo elemento podes usar  [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
- para encontrar o `tr` comum/mais próximo aconselho [.closest('tr')](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

No teu código creio que podes retirar a condição `if` pois o jQuery não dá erro caso não encontre o elemento. E se é um `input` podes usar o `.val()` que é a API para inputs.

```
$(this).find('td input[type=checkbox][name=chkSiapeServidor][value='+$('#siapeServidor').val()+']').prop('checked', true);
```